# Corona - Adding a listener to a table/array or to items in a table

Tags: arrays, lua, coronasdk, addeventlistener, lua-table

I'm trying to add a touch event to an image randomly picked from a table using the following code:

```
easyGame2 = function()
catTable = { 'catwhite', 'catblue', 'catred', 'catyellow', 'catgreen', 'catorange', 'catpink', 'catpurple'}
randomCat = catTable[math.random(#catTable)]

cat = display.newImageRect(randomCat..'.png', 50, 50)

cat.x = math.random(20, display.contentWidth-20)
cat.y = 0

cat.myName = randomCat
transition.to( cat, { rotation = cat.rotation-360, time=2000, y=500, 

onComplete=easyGame2}) 
end

easyGame2()

cat:addEventListener('touch', tapCat )

tapCat = function(event)
if event.phase == 'began' then
    score = score + 2
    display.remove(cat)
    cat = nil
   end  
end
```

It works the first time on touch and then it's as if there's no listener anymore. How do I make it work for every image that is chosen in the [math.random(#catTable)]

I have also tried this code:

```
local catTable = {}
cat1 = {}
cat1.imgpath = 'images/catwhite.png'
table.insert(catTable, cat1)
--cat1:addEventListener('touch', tapCat ) --causes errors

cat2 = {}
cat2.imgpath = 'images/catblue.png'
table.insert(catTable, cat2)

cat3 = {}
cat3.imgpath = 'images/catred.png'
table.insert(catTable, cat3)

cat4 = {}
cat4.imgpath = 'images/catyellow.png'
table.insert(catTable, cat4)

cat5 = {}
cat5.imgpath = 'images/catgreen.png'
table.insert(catTable, cat5)

cat6 = {}
cat6.imgpath = 'images/catorange.png'
table.insert(catTable, cat6)

cat7 = {}
cat7.imgpath = 'images/catpink.png'
table.insert(catTable, cat7)

cat8 = {}
cat8.imgpath = 'images/catpurple.png'
table.insert(catTable, cat8)

easyGame2 = function()
randomCat = catTable[math.random(#catTable)]

cat = display.newImageRect(randomCat.imgpath, 50, 50)

cat.x = math.random(20, display.contentWidth-20)
cat.y = 0

cat.myName = randomCat
transition.to( cat, { rotation = cat.rotation-360, time=2000, y=450,    onComplete=function(self)self.parent:remove(self);self=nil;end})

for i = 1, #catTable do 
        catTable[i]:addEventListener('touch', tapCat)--causes error
    end

end
```

which gives the error "181:attempt to call method 'addEventListener' (a nil value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I managed to solve it by making the following edits:

```
randomCat = catTable[math.random(#catTable)]
cat = display.newImageRect(randomCat..'.png', 50, 50)
transition.to( cat, { rotation = cat.rotation-360, time=2000, y=500,onComplete=easyGame2})
```

to

```
randomCat = math.random(#catTable)
cat = display.newImageRect(catTable[randomCat], 50, 50)
cat.type = randomCat
cat.trans = transition.to( cat, { rotation = cat.rotation-360, time=2000, y=550, onComplete=function(self)self.parent:remove(self);self=nil;end})
cat:addEventListener('touch', tapCat )
return cat
end

tapCat = function(event)
    catTouch = event.target
    transition.cancel (event.target.trans)

    if catTouch.type == catnormal then
        score = score + 5
    else 
        score = score + 10
    end
        display.remove(catTouch)
        cat = nil
    return true
end
```

Thanks to Vovahost for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

put your tapcat function anywhere above the listener like this

```
tapCat = function(event)
if event.phase == 'began' then
    score = score + 2
    display.remove(cat)
    cat = nil
   end  
end

cat:addEventListener('touch', tapCat )
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried that but it still only works on the first touch :/